# How to save ParseObject to disk in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, json, serialization, parse-platform

I need to save a list of ParseObjects to disk in C#, and was wondering if anyone had any recommendations on how to achieve this.

I am sure that the Parse .NET SDK has a means of converting ParseObjects to/from JSON since that is the format used during transit to parse server, but I haven't been able to find any public methods to do this :(

Hopefully someone has an answer for what should be an easy question! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using [Newtonsoft](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) You can do this

```
var jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(yourObject);
            using (StreamWriter writer =
            new StreamWriter("SerializedObject.json"))
                {
                    writer.Write(jsonString);
                }
```

To read the JSON file you can do this

```
using (StreamReader reader =
            new StreamReader("SerializedObject.json"))
            {
                string jsonString = reader.ReadToEnd();
                YourObject ObjectFromJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<YourObject>(jsonString);
            }
```

Comment: Thanks, `JsonConvert.SerializeObject()` does the trick.

We do have Newtonsoft, but for some reason there seems to be some other JSON library in our project so autocomplete was leading me towards that instead. Time for a library purge it seems :O

Comment: I should also note that I had to add the `[JsonObject(MemberSerialization.OptOut)]` attribute to the ParseObject subclass I wanted to serialize to ensure I was saving things like the ObjectId.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use ToString() method for parsing. You override the ToString() method in your Class and write parsing code on it.

For more information you can look into below link
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.tostring(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thanks for this, seems there may have been some confusion regarding the question though. I am using a library called Parse, not trying to parse some text or something. Worst library name ever haha